# Get the post's text using Graph Api Explorer

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to get the post's text using the post ID using `Graph Api` query at `Graph Api Explorer`. I am trying as;

```
GET/v2.8/{14346289902472_1788429604532785}
```

and

```
GET/v2.8/{14346289902472_1788429604532785} HTTP1.1
```

as documentation says;
[image]

But both prompts errors;

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: {14346289902472_1788429604532785}",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 803,
    "fbtrace_id": "AKd65t6sFzI"
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unknown path components: /1.1",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 2500,
    "fbtrace_id": "DbFPezM2JiA"
  }
}
```

**How can I get the post text using post ID?**

**Edit 1**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get that id from in the first place?

Visiting `https://www.facebook.com/14346289902472_1788429604532785` redirects to `https://www.facebook.com/ImranKhanOfficial/posts/1788429604532785`, and when you look up the page name `ImranKhanOfficial` via API, you find its page id is `143462899029472`.

So
`14346289902472`
instead of
`143462899029472`

And once you use *that* as the “prefix” for the post id, it works perfectly fine: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=143462899029472_1788429604532785&version=v2.8

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get a single feed item.

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/143462899029472/feed?id=1788429604532785



{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#12) singular statuses API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 12,
    "fbtrace_id": "CJpKkf7emZS"
  }
}
```

Graph api does not allow you to do this.

Just get the feed `GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/143462899029472/feed` and iterate over the results until you find the one you want.  If you don't find it in the first set, then paginate and get it in the next set.

Comment: So how to get the post text?

Comment: I added a bit at the end that should help you to do what you want.